# Approach for SharePoint 2010 file upload workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, document-library

[Crosspost from [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947523/appoach-for-sharepoint-2010-file-upload-workflow).]

I'm working on a project that is basically a file upload "wizard" that basically does the following:

Entry form to select document library and enter some basic info.
Enter additional library-specific information.
Tie in some calendar events.

**My goals are:**

- Create this as a sandbox solution using Visual Studio
- Avoid hacks and reinventing existing functionality as much as possible.

**Some SP features I have run across that might be useful:**

- Content organizer feature.
- Association forms.
- Declarative workflows.

**Possible approaches I've considered:**

1. A content organizer library that kicks off a workflow on submission. Not sure what the user experience for this would be like. Really hoping to keep to a single link -> Next -> Next -> Done kind of approach.
2. A declarative workflow with custom actions containing all the complexity.
3. An association form in front of the built-in document upload form for each library with a follow-on association form for calendar events.

Is this feasible and if so which approach is simplest?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to create a simple interace where the user can choose any document library he likes and upload a document to it. Is it correct?

Comment: @Moussa - The choice is made based on the data they enter. I don't want them to have to try and decide which library to upload to.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come to my own conclusions on this. I've decided to go with a Drop Off library as part of the Content Organizer built-in feature (#1 above). This appears to be the simplest approach so far since I can do the majority through configuration in the Entity.xml files of the features. Many of the other methods I tried seems like they would require functionality not available in a Sandbox solution.

In order to achieve this, I defined site columns and added them to custom Document Type, then added this Document Type to all libraries. Using the Drop Off library, I can define rules to move the file based on one of the fields in the custom Document Type. I'm hoping to do any follow-up steps as a workflow that kicks off on the Drop Off library when a file is uploaded or as an Associated Form.